Forms of a coset of two subgroups.
I have been self-study graduate level mathematics, and have begun studying cosets and Lagrange's Theorem. I am having some difficulty understanding cosets. I am trying to complete the following proof, but am unsure if I am using the concept of cosets correctly. Is my proof correct? Thank you!
Let H $\subseteq$ K $\subseteq$ G be groups. Assume $g_1K, ..., g_nK$ is a complete list of the cosets of K in G, and assume $k_1H,..., k_mH$ is a complete list of the cosets of H in K.
Prove that every $a \in G$ is in some coset of the form $g_ik_jH$.
My attempt:
Let $a \in G$
Now, a, being an element of G, is in some coset of the form $g_iK $= {$g_ix | x \in K$} for some $1 \leq i \leq n$, so $a = g_ix$.
Also, x, being an element of K, is in some coset of the form $k_jH$ = {$k_jh | h \in H$} for some $1 \leq j \leq m$, so $x = k_jh$.
Substituting, we can see that $a = g_ik_jh \in$ {$g_ik_jh | h \in H$} $= g_ik_jH$.
This proves that every $a \in G$ is in a coset of the form $g_ik_jH$.

That's most of it.  You've shown that the union of the cosets $g_ik_jH$ is equal to $G$.  But you also need to show that all of these cosets are distinct.

Thank you! Why is it necessary to show distinction in this case?

Please do not re-post a closed question; instead, edit the old question and request that it be re-opened.

@CZed because that's what a complete list of cosets is: they are mutually distinct cosets whose disjoint union is the whole group.
